# Fill page with lines

Tags: luatex

I am trying to put together a book, that could be thought of as a kind of book of anniversaries with some certain prefilled entries.  So there is one page per day, and most days are going to have an entry or two.  After that I just want the page filled up with lines, so that someone can easily come and add a new one since the book was printed. I just can't work out how to do that. I looked into how `\dotfill` works, but it did not help when I tried messing with it, and Google turned up nothing. Any idea how this can be done?

Needs to work in lualatex.

EDIT: Inspired by the first answer I now have this, it is a complete but broken example of what I want.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
\RequirePackage[a5paper,includehead,top=0.5in,inner=0.75in,outer=0.5in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}


\newsavebox{\thetopstuffbox}
\newlength{\thetopstuffht}

\newcommand\Linepage[1]{%
  \vbox to \dimexpr\textheight-#1-2cm\relax {\leaders\hbox to \linewidth{\rule{0pt}{1cm}\hrulefill}\vfil}
}

\usepackage{changepage}

\newcommand{\personentry}[3][3em]{%
  \nopagebreak%
  \begin{adjustwidth}{#1}{0pt}%
    \ignorespaces \hspace{-3em}\textbf{#2} #3
  \end{adjustwidth}%
  \nopagebreak%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\sbox{\thetopstuffbox}{%
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \section*{September 17}

      \personentry{Joe Blow}{He did some important stuff and we want to remember him for it. He was a top bloke and did a lot of good work, and we are thankful for it and did I mention everything that he did.}

      \personentry{Jane Doe}{Also did a lot of stuff what we really want too remember her for it because if we don't we are going to feel really guiltly about it since I am now just rambling on.}

    \end{minipage}%
}\usebox{\thetopstuffbox}\newline\Linepage{\ht\thetopstuffbox}

\pagebreak


\noindent\sbox{\thetopstuffbox}{%
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \section*{September 18}
      \personentry{Joe Blow}{He did some important stuff and we want to remember him for it. He was a top bloke and did a lot of good work, and we are thankful for it and did I mention everything that he did.}

      \personentry{Jane Doe}{Also did a lot of stuff what we really want too remember her for it because if we don't we are going to feel really guiltly about it since I am now just rambling on.}

    \end{minipage}%
}\usebox{\thetopstuffbox}\newline\Linepage{\ht\thetopstuffbox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to solve this sort of problem some time ago with a questionnaire. Agree with StefanH that leaders are the best way to go. I think you need an environment to do this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}

\usepackage[a5paper,includehead,top=0.5in,inner=0.75in,outer=0.5in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}

\newcommand\Linepage[1][0.25in]{% Change to suit
  \vbox to \dimexpr\textheight-\pagetotal-#1\relax {% Let TeX do the work...
    \leaders\hbox to \linewidth{\rule{0pt}{#1}\hrulefill}\vfil
  }%
}

\newenvironment{formatpage}[1]{%
    \section*{#1}
}{
    \Linepage
    \pagebreak
}

\newcommand{\personentry}[3][3em]{%
  \nopagebreak%
  \noindent
  \hangindent#1
  \textbf{#2\ }#3
  \par
  \nopagebreak%
}

%% Usage:
%% \begin{formatpage}{<date>}
%%   \personentry{<name 1>}{<info>}
%%   \personentry{<name 2>}{<info>}
%%   ...
%% \end{formatpage}

\begin{document}

\begin{formatpage}{September 17}

      \personentry{Joe Blow}{He did some important stuff and we want to remember him for it. He was a top bloke and did a lot of good work, and we are thankful for it and did I mention everything that he did.}

      \personentry{Jane Doe}{Also did a lot of stuff what we really want too remember her for it because if we don't we are going to feel really guiltly about it since I am now just rambling on, and on and on and on and on and on\dots}
\end{formatpage}

\begin{formatpage}{September 18}
      \personentry{Joe Blow}{He did some important stuff and we want to remember him for it. He was a top bloke and did a lot of good work, and we are thankful for it and did I mention everything that he did.}

      \personentry{Jane Doe}{Also did a lot of stuff what we really want too remember her for it because if we don't we are going to feel really guiltly about it since I am now just rambling on.}

\end{formatpage}

\end{document}
```

[image: text with lined pages]

Comment: Awesome, exactly as it is supposed to look.  Now I just need write the script dump the database into tex.  I was also a one point trying to use an environment as it allows for anything to be put inside, but I could not work it out. Latex is just not my strong point.

Answer (score 5):

The lines can be drawn with `\leaders`, the problem is to find the end of the page. Here I started with a header for the day and then filling up with lines. The height of the line part is just `\textheight-10mm`, where `10mm` is just a number that fitted. If you describe more about what the header should contain it should be possible to put it in a box and then finding the height of that instead. The distance between the lines is set to `1cm`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\Linepage[2]{%
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\linewidth}
    \Huge #1
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.7\linewidth}
    #2
  \end{minipage}\newline
  \vbox to \dimexpr\textheight-10mm\relax {\leaders\hbox to \linewidth{\rule{0pt}{1cm}\hrulefill}\vfil}
}
\begin{document}
\Linepage{Sept 17}{Someone is sitting in the shade today because someone planted a tree a long time ago.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I add number lines? E.G \Lines{10}, I get 10 lines.

Comment: Ok this is useful, but does not do everything I need.  The page layout would have a `\section` at the top with the date (1st January etc.).  Then several entries (a few days have none, some have a few).  Each entry is the person's name and something about them.  The example as given would mean working out `\textheight-10mm` for every day of the year, which would be tedious.  It would be nice if it was just auto computed. I will update my question, with a now half working but still broken example.